# Column Width no effect in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery to create my table but the column width has no effect, I tried `autoWidth:false`, I tried to use % but nothing works

```
    var table = $('#table').DataTable({
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "order": [8, "desc"],
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            if (data.IsActive === false) {
                $(row).addClass('inactive');
            }
        },
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "paging": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 200,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Inventory/Get",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "complete": function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        },
        "buttons": [
            {
                extend: 'excel',
                text: 'Download Excel',
                className: "btn",
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [1, 2, 3]
                }
            }
        ],
        "columns":
            [
                { data: "ID", title: "", render: EditTemmplate, bSortable: false, searchable: false, width: "5%" },
                { data: "StockCode", title: "Model #" },
                { data: "Description", title: "Description" },
                { data: "Interface", title: "Interface" },
                { data: "Capacity", title: "Capacity" },
                { data: "Tier1Price", title: "T1" },
                { data: "ResellerPrice", title: "Reseller" },
                { data: "RetailPrice", title: "Retail" },
                { data: "SOH", title: "SOH" },
            ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { targets: [2], width: "350px" },
            { targets: '_all', width: "10px" }
        ]
    });
```

I tried

```
        "columnDefs": [
            { targets: [2], width: "50%" },
            { targets: '_all', width: "10%" }
        ]
```

And also

```
        "columnDefs": [
            { targets: [2], width: "80%" },
            { targets: [1,3,4,5,6,7,8], width: "1%" },
        ]
```

It seems that the following is causing the column width not to work

```
    var columns = table.settings()[0].aoColumns;
    var text = "<tr>";
    table.columns().every(function (index) {
        var title = columns[index].sTitle;
        if (columns[index].bSearchable) {
            text += '<td style="width:' + columns[index].sWidth + '"><input type="text" colid="' + index + '" class="form-control seach_coll" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" /></td>'
        } else {
            text += "<td></td>"
        }
    });
    text += "</tr>";
    $("#table thead").append(text);
    $(".seach_coll").on('keyup change', function () {
        var id = this.getAttribute("colid");
        var that = table.column(id);
        that.search(this.value).draw();
    });
```

The following line seems to be the problem

```
text += '<th style="width:' + columns[index].sWidth + '"><input type="text" colid="' + index + '" class="form-control seach_coll" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" /></th>'
```

Comment: Try implementing it in `columnDefs`.

Comment: No affect, see updated question

Comment: It should work, have you checked your CSS? or the table markup?

Comment: Yes I have checked, it didn't do anything to my table, I am using standard jquery databales and bootstrap. It adds the values to the html when generated but it has no effect

Comment: Ok I think I found the issue

Comment: Nice, you did assign width to your table cell.

Comment: Yes I added the width to the search cells, but it seems that it doesn't work, If I remove the search collumns then the width takes effect

Comment: You can actually render that directly on your Datatables.

Comment: I've build mine from the sample on jquery website, It seems that the following line is causing the width issue (see question update)

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the trouble line with the width property instead of sWidth

```
 text += '<td style="width:' + columns[index].sWidth + '">...
                                   // notice  ^^
```

should be

```
 text += '<td style="width:' + columns[index].width + '">...
```

or you could set sWidth in columnDefs

```
 "columnDefs": [
            { targets: [2], sWidth: "80%" },
            { targets: [1,3,4,5,6,7,8], sWidth: "1%" },
        ]
```

---

You could also try to resize the columns on the fly like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#table > td').css("max-width", "10px"); 
   });
```

Comment: width also populates sWidth so that is not the problem

Comment: in fact, you should definately give the 2nd one a try.. or use jquery to resize the columns on-the-fly